# Go program for indexing file systems

Tags: linux, go

I'm coding a program to map very big file systems (over 100TB). It is using [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) to list files/directories. In the end, the program is supposed to make text files (that will be merged later) containing paths of everything on file system from the point I executed it. Problem is that it keeps cycling and printing the same output to the file, so I suppose mistake is somewhere in declaration/rewriting of some variables. What do you think?

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "os"
)
// declaring variables
var count int
var start_dir string
var cmd *exec.Cmd
var sizeof_dir_array int
var counter int
var index_output string
var dirs string
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
var byte_out []byte
var err error
var err1 error
var dir_array []string

func find_indexes(starting_directory string) {
    start_dir = starting_directory
    sizeof_dir_array = 0
    counter = 0
    index_output = "" 
    // deciding to use start_dir or not
    if start_dir != "" {
        // declaring byte output that contain file indexes and issigning it to index_output variable
        byte_out, err = exec.Command("fd", "-d", "1", "-a", ".", start_dir).Output()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        index_output = string(byte_out)
        // issigning string containing directories to cmd variable
        cmd = exec.Command("fd", "-d", "1", "-a", "-t", "d", ".", start_dir)
    }else {
        byte_out, err = exec.Command("fd", "-d", "1", "-a").Output()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        index_output = string(byte_out)
        cmd = exec.Command("fd", "-d", "1", "-a", "-t", "d")
    }
    // parsing from cmd to dirs variable
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err1 = cmd.Run()
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err1) + ": " + stderr.String())
    return
    }
    dirs = out.String()
    // writing index_output to a file
    file, err2 := os.Create("{your_path}/index-" + strconv.Itoa(count) + ".txt")
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot create file", err2)
    }
    count++
    fmt.Fprintf(file, index_output)
    file.Close()
    // putting dirs from string to dir_array 
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(string(dirs)))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        sizeof_dir_array++
    }
    dir_array = make([]string, sizeof_dir_array)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        dir_array[counter] = scanner.Text()
        counter++
    }
    // if there are no more dirs, recursion continues
    if dirs != "" {
        for _, val := range dir_array {
            find_indexes(val)
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    count = 0
    find_indexes("")
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use golangs internal functions instead oft executing external programs like fd

Comment: Agreed, throw it all away and read the directories yourself in native Go code.